# How to get elevated access to launch the app pool recycle?

Tags: powershell, iis, cmd

I just used this code (on a ps1 file) to recycle my ApplicationPool:

```
$WebserverName="MySite"

# Load IIS module:
Import-Module WebAdministration

# Get pool name by the site name:
$pool = (Get-Item "IIS:\Sites\$WebserverName"| Select-Object applicationPool).applicationPool
# Recycle the application pool:
  Restart-WebAppPool $pool
```

But it show me this error:

Import-Module : Process should have elevated status to access IIS

So, i searched on internet and i was able to create this .bat file:

```
@ECHO OFF
@cd ..
@SET DebugLevel=3
@SET PowerShellScriptPath=.\Header.ps1
@SET CurrentScriptName=%~n0.ps1

@PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList ' -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%PowerShellScriptPath%"" ""%CurrentScriptName%"" ""%DebugLevel%""' -Verb RunAs}"

@pause
```

I runned it, logged with the administrator user but it shows me a blue screen (from powershell) and suddenly it stops.

I did something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@SET PowerShellScriptPath=.\Header.ps1
@PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList ' -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File  ""%PowerShellScriptPath%"" ' -Verb RunAs}"
```

You batch has some extra stuff you don't need.

Comment: But i need to pass it some params, DebugLevel and CurrentScriptName

Answer (score -2):

Ensure that the user running this process has admin rights within the box you're attempting to run this against. This wound up solving the issue for me.